# Sequelize - update record, and return result

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with MySQL. For example if I do:

```
models.People.update({OwnerId: peopleInfo.newuser},
        {where: {id: peopleInfo.scenario.id}})
        .then(function (result) {
            response(result).code(200);

        }).catch(function (err) {
        request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
       ).code(200);
    });
```

I am not getting information back if the people model was succesfully updated or not. Variable result is just an array with one element, 0=1

How can I know for certain that the record was updated or not.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Here's what I think you're looking for.

```
db.connections.update({
  user: data.username,
  chatroomID: data.chatroomID
}, {
  where: { socketID: socket.id },
  returning: true,
  plain: true
})
.then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);   
  // result = [x] or [x, y]
  // [x] if you're not using Postgres
  // [x, y] if you are using Postgres
});
```

From Sequelize [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/):
The promise returns an array with one or two elements. The first element `x` is always the number of affected rows, while the second element `y` is the actual affected rows (only supported in postgres with `options.returning` set to `true`.)

Assuming you are using Postgres, you can access the updated object with `result[1].dataValues`.

You must set `returning: true` option to tell Sequelize to return the object. And `plain: true` is just to return the object itself and not the other messy meta data that might not be useful.

Comment: I am using MySQL. I will test it with. Thanks for reply

Comment: I was not able to make it work with MySql. I guess this is only Postgresql feature :(

Comment: Also, despite what the docs say, I get `undefined` as the first parameter and  the _number of affected rows_ as the second parameter (using sqlite). To fix this I did `result = result.filter(Boolean);` before processing anything.

Comment: Is there a way to specify returned columns? I'm working with Postgress

Comment: what does mean x in "[x, y] if you are using Postgres" ?

Comment: @stackdave `x` would be the number of affected rows, while `y` is the actual affected rows (only supported in postgres with options.returning true.)

Comment: @nickang thanks, I'm working  with postgress and options.returning true, with .update i get always x null, and y the record data, with .create i get directly y record data, no x!, it's possible to unify return [x, y] to .create and .update sequelize methods? and i missed a config maybe? because x is always null in .update

Comment: @stackdave That's weird. Could it be that you're missing a curly brace somewhere, causing your first and second params into `update` to be messed up? I'm not sure what the return value for `x` will be if no rows are being updated (should be 0 or null). Try digging into the docs for `.update()` - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/instances.html

Comment: The "plain" option seems to not be supported for the update statement (http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/#updatevalues-options-promisearrayaffectedcount-affectedrows)

Comment: As docs say: it returns the affected rows (only for postgres)

Comment: It seems that plain: true is deprecated. you can use save() instead. Look at my answer below.

Comment: it is not working for mysql , is there a way around

Comment: This definitely worked, but the `data[0].data.Values api` is wonky. BTW I am on Sequelize 6.12

Comment: in here stable v6 , there is no save operation , its only on after create , not update , https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#simple-update-queries  so how to solve then ?

Answer (score 33):

You can just find the item and update its properties and then save it. 
The save() results in a UPDATE query to the db

```
const job = await Job.findOne({where: {id, ownerId: req.user.id}});
if (!job) {
    throw Error(`Job not updated. id: ${id}`);
}

job.name = input.name;
job.payload = input.payload;
await job.save();
```

On Postgres:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE "jobs" SET "payload"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" = $3
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution that works universally. Thanks.

Comment: This needs 2 queries instead of 1

Answer (score 19):

Update function of sequelize returns a number of affected rows (first parameter of result array).

You should call find to get updated row

```
models.People.update({OwnerId: peopleInfo.newuser},
    {where: {id: peopleInfo.scenario.id}})
    .then(() => {return models.People.findById(peopleInfo.scenario.id)})
    .then((user) => response(user).code(200))
    .catch((err) => {
         request.server.log(['error'], err.stack);
      });
```

Comment: So it seems the only way is to call find immediately after the update?

Comment: anyway you should use find function.

Comment: you can call `find` function first, then do update with this object without using `where`

Comment: if you're using PostgreSQL you can define `returning` option to `true` that returns affected rows

Answer (score 8):

Finally i got it. returning true wont work in mysql , we have to use findByPk in order hope this code will help.

```
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
User.update({
        subject: params.firstName, body: params.lastName, status: params.status
    },{
        returning:true,
        where: {id:id }                             
    }).then(function(){
        let response = User.findById(params.userId);                      
        resolve(response);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 4):

same thing you can do with async-await, especially to avoid nested Promises
You just need to create async function :)

```
const asyncFunction = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        //update 
        const updatePeople = await models.People.update({OwnerId: peopleInfo.newuser},
                                    {where: {id: peopleInfo.scenario.id}})
        if (!updatePeople) throw ('Error while Updating');
        // fetch updated data
        const returnUpdatedPerson =  await models.People.findById(peopleInfo.scenario.id)
        if(!returnUpdatedPerson) throw ('Error while Fetching Data');
        res(user).code(200);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another way - use `findByPk` static method and `update` not-static method together. For example:

```
let person = await models.People.findByPk(peopleInfo.scenario.id);
if (!person) {
  // Here you can handle the case when a person is not found
  // For example, I return a "Not Found" message and a 404 status code
}
person = await person.update({ OwnerId: peopleInfo.newuser });
response(person).code(200);
```

Note this code must be inside an asynchronous function.

Comment: so there is no one way for mysql ? we must be re-fetch instead of update can be detect if the data is alr exist on db , all of comment what i thought is seem to be twice query for mysql.

Comment: its not solve still undefined because the question is mysql , your code just replace `person` to update query where its undefined of affect and result is `[ 1 ]`.
still looking for best code, no need re-fetch data after update data.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the model to update first, and call set() then save() on it. Returning this object will give you the updated model.

Although this might not be the shortest way to do it, I prefer it because you can handle not found and update errors separately.

```
const instance = await Model.findOne({
  where: {
    'id': objectId
  }
});

if (instance && instance.dataValues) {
  instance.set('name', objectName);
  return await instance.save(); // promise rejection (primary key violation…) might be thrown here
} else {
  throw new Error(`No Model was found for the id ${objectId}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgres and updating one row.

```
  try {
    const result = await MODELNAME.update(req.body, {
      where: { id: req.params.id },
      returning: true
    });
    if (!result) HANDLEERROR()
    const data = result[1][0].get();

    res.status(200).json({ success: true, data });
  } catch (error) {
    HANDLEERROR()
  }
```