# Updating model with Sequelize JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm building a simple API with Express and Sequelize JS. I tried to update an record with `req.School` but nothing happend. I shared the code below. Also I got no error for output. Can you help me ?

Controller js

```
module.exports.params = function(req, res, next, id) {
School.find({
          where: {
            id: id
          }
        })
        .then(function(school) {
          if (!school) {
            next(new Error("School not found by given ID"));
          }else {
            req.School = school;
            next();
          }
        }, function(err) {
          next(err);
        });
    };
module.exports.delete = function (req,res,next) {
    req.School.Status = SysEnums.Deleted;
      School.update(req.School,{
        where:{
          id:req.School.id
        }
      }).then(function (deleted) {
        res.json(deleted);
      });
    };
```

Route JS

```
var router = require("express").Router();
var controller = require("../Controllers/SchoolController");

router.param("id",controller.params);

router.route("/").get(controller.get);

router.route("/:id").get(controller.getOne).delete(controller.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: why don't you use data which has been submitted, `req.body` in update function as first parameter instead of `req.school`.

Comment: It seems like you're storing data which is saved in DB in `req.school` so that would give you old data only.

Comment: As the Router Js when user send id in query string first hits the param and The param finds the record with that ID attaches to req.School. Then hits the Delete. To delete I just change Status to deleted and then update. But did not work. @PandhiBhaumik

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543424/3584881), it shows manuall parameters and also I guess `req.school` is having NULL I guess, confirm about that too.

Comment: I came across that post before, it works but lets assume I'm updating 10 property in my model, I need to assign every value to every property that model has. I'm looking for more generic way to update if it's possible. Also when I `console.log` the `req.School` it has all properties from model@PandhiBhaumik

Comment: Can u not hit req.school.save. instead of making a delete call

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you mean, can you be more specific ? @Shivam

Comment: Since request.School has the model instance updated, so you can call the save method on it.
So in the delete route do
req.School.save()

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that. I' ll try this now. Also @PandhiBhaumik showed me a Build method I'll try both and share the results.

Comment: @Shivam I tried `req.School.Save()` gave error "req.School.Save is not a function".

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik I tried `School.Build()` also gave me an error same as above.

Comment: I fixed, finally I found. I made a syntax error.  I'll share what I did. Thank you for you help. @PandhiBhaumik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the params method, req.School is a sequelize object. Here is the params method.

```
module.exports.params = function(req, res, next, id) {

  School.find({
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    })
    .then(function(school) {
      if (!school) {
        next(new Error("School not found by given ID"));
      }else {
        req.School = school;
        next();
      }
    }, function(err) {
      next(err);
    });
};
```

As @Shivam said it' s a sequelize object, I could use provided methods. I want to soft delete my record, so here is my delete method with Sequelize JS.

```
module.exports.delete = function(req, res, next) {

  try {
    req.School.Status = SysEnums.Deleted;
    req.School.save().then(function(entity) {
      res.json(entity);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

@PandhiBhaumik

Thank you for your help. I' ll try to use build method as a second option.