# Sequelize .update() always returning [0]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Edit: Please read edit at bottom.

I am using sequelize, trying to findOrCreate a row in a mySQL db, and then immediately make an update to newly created rows. My .update function always returns [0], even if hard-coding known existing values into the query.

```
const importToSqlBI = async (metadataArray, filepath) => {
  metadataArray.shift(); // remove the header row
  let release;
  ReleaseBI.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      rel_num: metadataArray[0].release
    }
  }).then(([response, created]) => {
    release = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    let numOnly = release.rel_num.substring(1, 3);
    release.rel_num_only = numOnly;

    if(created){
      updateRelease(release);
    }
    let z = mapArray(metadataArray, release);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("uploads.js:", 128, err);
  });
  return "finished";
};

const updateRelease = (release) => {
  let z = ReleaseBI.update({...release}, {
    where: {
      rel_id: release.rel_id
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    return response;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("uploads.js:", 149, err);
  });
  return z; // this always returns [0], meaning nothing was updated
};
```

This is the code that sequelize spits out in the console. Notice there are never any values in the query, only question marks (my object contains all the correct values and the columns names are spelled correctly with the right data types).

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `releases` SET `rel_id`=?,`rel_num`=? WHERE `rel_id` = ?
```

It looks like it's not even grabbing anything from the object being passed into the query.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: If I change the column I'm updating (from rel_num_only to rel_num), the query passes. Both are valid columns in SQL, in fact, I generated the model using auto-sequelize. So sequelize doesn't recognize the column from the model it itself made...?

The sequelize model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('releases', {
    rel_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    rel_num: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    },
    rel_num_only: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'releases',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
};
```

Comment: updateRelease method returns before it resolve the promise, so you need to wait to resolve the promise and for that you can use...  await updateRelease(release)

Comment: @Garry I don't think that's the issue, or at least I tried it and the problem persisted

Comment: I think you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524938/sequelize-update-record-and-return-result

Comment: where do you get this `.update() always returning [0]` , on which line , where do you console it? can't see in your code.

Comment: @VivekDoshi its the return value of updateRelease.

Comment: @이준형 I don't need to actually see the updated value. If it returns [1], I know it was updated, and that's enough for me. The problem is maybe that it's not recognizing that that column exists in the table / model

Comment: So there's three columns in this table, rel_id, rel_num, rel_num_only. When a row is created, rel_num and rel_num_only are allowed to be null, but I immediately try to update its value. If I try to update rel_num, I get the error as described in this post. If I try to update rel_num_only, a column with an identical data type (VARCHAR) and structure as rel_num, the update is a success. The tables were generated with auto-sequelize as stated before. I don't know how to describe my issue any better.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by creating my function async.

```
const importToSqlBI = async (metadataArray, filepath) => {
  metadataArray.shift(); 
  ReleaseBI.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      rel_num: metadataArray[0].release
    }
  }).then(async ([response, created]) => {
    let release = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

    let composersArray = await metadataArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      let composers = [];
      curr.composer_name.split("/").forEach((composer, i) => {
        composers.push({
          composer_name: composer.trim(),
          pro: curr.pro.includes("/") ? curr.pro.split("/")[i].trim() : curr.pro,
          publisher: curr.publisher.includes("/") ? curr.publisher.split("/")[i].trim() : curr.publisher,
          composer_split: curr.composer_split.includes("/") ? curr.composer_split.split("/")[i].trim() : curr.composer_split,
          publisher_split: curr.publisher_split.includes("/") ? curr.publisher_split.split("/")[i].trim() : curr.publisher_split,
          newUploadCount: metadataArray.filter(x => x.composer_name.includes(composer)).length
        });
      });
      let everyNewComposerInAccumulator = composers.every(x => acc.find(y => x.composer_name === y.composer_name));
      let newComposers = everyNewComposerInAccumulator ?
        [] :
        composers.filter(x => acc.every(y => y.composer_name !== x.composer_name));
      return [...acc, ...newComposers];
    }, []);

    let uniquePublishers = await composersArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return !acc.some(composer => composer.publisher_name.includes(curr.publisher)) ?
        [...acc, { pro: /\((\S+)\)/.exec(curr.publisher)[1], publisher_name: curr.publisher }] :
        acc;
    }, []);

    uniquePublishers = await Promise.all(uniquePublishers.map(publisher =>
      findOrCreatePublisherBI(publisher)
    ));

    const foundComposers = await Promise.all(composersArray.map(composer =>
      findOrCreateComposerBI(composer, uniquePublishers.find(p => p.publisher_name === composer.publisher))
    ));

    let keywordsArray = await composersArray.map(x => ({
      composer_name: x.composer_name,
      newUploadCount: x.newUploadCount
    })).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      let composerSubwordsArray = curr.composer_name.includes(" ") ?
        curr.composer_name.split(" ").map(x => ({ keyword: x.toLowerCase(), newUploadCount: curr.newUploadCount})) :
        [{ keyword: curr.composer_name.toLowerCase(),
          newUploadCount: curr.newUploadCount
        }];

      return [...acc, ...composerSubwordsArray,
        { keyword: curr.composer_name.toLowerCase(), newUploadCount: curr.newUploadCount },
      ];
    }, []);

    // removes keywords less than 3 in length: irrelevant keywords
    keywordsArray = keywordsArray.filter(x => x.keyword.length >= 3);

    keywordsArray = await Promise.all(keywordsArray.map(keyword => {
      if(!forbiddenKeywords.includes(keyword.keyword)){
        return findOrCreateKeywordsBI(keyword);
      }
    }).filter(x => x !== undefined));

    let sqlData = await objArrayParseBI(metadataArray, release, foundComposers, keywordsArray);

    // and insert them into our SQL database
    createCues(sqlData, metadataArray, foundComposers, filepath);

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("uploads.ctrl.js:", 87, err);
  });
};
```